# how to get data from API in android component and pass that data to react native to render it on UI?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am making a request to an API using retrofit and coroutines (following MVVM architecture) in the android component of react native project. Now I have to fetch all the data (products of a shopping application) in the android component and send that data to react native to render it on UI.

any ideas?

Comment: if you are fetching the data natively on android then you need to follow steps of building `native-modules` on react-native 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro
this is the only way so far to connect native code with react-native